# Embbebing videos

Tags: video, embedding, qualtrics, pause

I am trying to embed videos in Qualtrics, but I would like to restrict the respondent's option to share, like, and pause the video. Is there any way or platform that allows me to do that? Thank you!

When I insert autoplay and take all the controls, the videos do not load appropriately. Vimeo does not allow me to take out the pause bottom. And I would like the video to be a one-shot one without any respondents' interaction basically.